# Let $R =\mathbb Z[\sqrt2]$ and $M =\{a+b\sqrt2\in R: 5\mid a \text{ and }5\mid b\} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals

Let $$ R =\mathbb Z[\sqrt2]$$ and $$M =\{a+b\sqrt2\in R: 5\mid a \text{ and }5\mid b\} $$

1. Show that $M$ is an ideal of the ring $R$ .
2. Show that if $5\nmid a $ or $5\nmid b$, then $5\nmid (a^2+b^2)$ for  $a, b\in\mathbb Z$
3. Hence show that if $N$ is an ideal of $R$ properly containing $M$, then $N = R$. .
   4 Show that R/M is a field, and give two distinct non-zero elements of this 
   field.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Probably in point 2 it should be $a^2 - 2b^2$...

Comment: For (ii) compute the squares $1^2=1$, $2^2=4=-1$, $3^2=9=-1$ and $4^2=16=1$ mod $5$. Therefore, $a^2-2b^2$ is not divisible by $5$ when $a$ or $5$ is not divisible by $5$.

Comment: Can you give it in detail. The question had errors

Comment: I think the new edit made it wrong again: for part 2, $a=1, b=2$ gives us $a^2+b^2=5$ is a clear counterexample

Comment: Yes the edit made it wrong

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, in point 2 the thesis should be $5 \nmid a^2 - 2b^2$, otherwise it's false.

1. Let $5a + 5b\sqrt{2}$ and $5c + 5d\sqrt{2}$ be elements fo $M$. Then $$(5a + 5b\sqrt{2}) + (5c + 5d\sqrt{2}) = 5(a + c) + 5(b + d)\sqrt{2} \in M$$ so $M$ is closed under sum. Also, if $x + y\sqrt{2} \in R$ then $$(5a + 5b\sqrt{2})(x + y\sqrt{2}) = 5(ax + 2by) + 5(ay + bx)\sqrt{2} \in M$$ This proves that $M$ is an ideal of $R$.
2. Suppose there exist $a$, $b$ not both divisible by $5$such that $5 \mid a^2 - 2b^2$. If $5 \mid b$ then also $5 \mid a$, which is not possible. If $5 \nmid 5$, let $b^{-1}$ be the inverse of $b$ modulo $5$. Then $$a^2 - 2b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{5} \implies (ab^{-1})^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$$ But it can be easily checked that $2$ is not a quadratic residue $\pmod{5}$, whence the contradiction.
3. Let $s + t\sqrt{2}$ be an element of $N$ such that $5 \nmid s$ or $5 \nmid t$. From point 2 we know that $5 \nmid N(s + t\sqrt{2}) = s^2 - 2t^2$.

   Now we prove that there exists $s' + t'\sqrt{2} \in N$ where $5 \nmid s'$ and $5 \mid t'$. If $5 \mid t$ we are done, so suppose that $5 \nmid t$. Choose $k$ such that $5 \mid s + kt$, for instance $k = -t^{-1}$ where $tt^{-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$. Then let $(s + t\sqrt{2})(k + \sqrt{2}) = s' + t'\sqrt{2}$. By definition of ideal, $s' + t'\sqrt{2} \in N$. We have $t' = s + kt \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$. Also, $$s'^2 - 2t'^2 = N(s' + t'\sqrt{2}) = N((s + t\sqrt{2})(k + \sqrt{2})) = \\ = N(s + t\sqrt{2})N(k + \sqrt{2}) = (s^2 - 2t^2)(k^2 - 2)$$ and since, from point 2 again, $5 \nmid k^2 - 2$, we derive that $5 \nmid s'^2 - 2t'^2$ and thus $5 \nmid s'$.

   Now take $m$ such that $ms' \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$. Then $m(s' + t'\sqrt{2}), \: (1 - ms') - mt'\sqrt{2} \in N$ and, since $N$ is closed under sum, $$m(s' + t'\sqrt{2}) + ((1 - ms') - mt'\sqrt{2}) = 1$$ is an element of $N$ as well. Hence the conclusion is trivial.

Comment: Its $$a^2+b^2$$

Comment: You've been given a counterexample for this.

Comment: I cannot do it..... Please i need help

Comment: I could not solve no. 3 question

Comment: How to solve point no.  4